# How to make owl carousel slide from left to right?

Tags: jquery, slider, owl-carousel

I have set of rows which i.e multiple sliders but the thing is i need **even rows** to slide from **right to left** (*by default it is*) and **odd ones** from **left to right which im unable to figure**.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap carousel by CSS only (right to left, RTL)

HTML-----------------------------------

```
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="..." alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                ...
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="..." alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                ...
              </div>
            </div>
            ...
          </div>

          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
```

CSS------------------------------

```
                /* Make the images wide and responsive. */
            #myCarousel img {
              height: auto;
              max-width: 100%;
              width: 100%;
            }

            /* Change the order of the indicators. 
               Return them to the center of the slide. */
            .carousel-indicators {
              width: auto;
              margin-left: 0;
              transform: translateX(-50%);
            }
            .carousel-indicators li {
              float: right;
              margin: 1px 4px;
            }
            .carousel-indicators .active {
              margin: 0 3px;
            }

            /* Change the direction of the transition. */
            @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
              .carousel-inner > .item.next,
              .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
                left: 0;
                -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
              }
              .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
              .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
                left: 0;
                -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
              }
            }
```